# How do I get a reference to an Image in Unity 2019.3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

So normally in Unity, I can get a reference to a component on a gameobject by using `GetComponent<Type>()`. In this instance, I'd like to do a simple `GetComponentInChildren<Image>()` so I can do some code to the image. Normal unity stuff.

But in 2019.3, it seems like I can't do that, since `Image` isn't a component anymore.

`ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Image' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.`

So I'm not sure how I would get a reference to an Image "component" on a RectTransform in order to do stuff to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Silly answer, but I figured it out. Leaving here for posterity.

my `Image` type was incorrectly defined as a `Unity.UIElements.Image` rather than what I wanted, `Unity.UI.Image`. That is to say, my script was `using Unity.UIElements;` instead of the correct one.

Very cool to have two different classes with the same name.